# Squashed commits return after rebase to parent branch it Git

Tags: git, rebase, pull-request

I have a PR with 8 commits. I opened the branch in the command line and did `git rebase -i HEAD~8` then went through the process fixing any conflicts and got it down to a single commit. When I push the updated branch it shows 1 commit message but 160 changed files. I've only changed about 10. So... I did a rebase against the development branch which fixed the number of changed files but all the squashed commits come back.

What step/process am I missing here?

-- edit --

- I run `git rebase -i HEAD~8`
- The commit I need to "preserve" is the last one. If I leave it as `pick` and set the other 7 to `squash` I get an error so I move it to the top
- set the 7 below it to squash
- save with `:wq`
- get conflicts so I resolve them in vsCode
- use `git add .` then `get rebase --continue`
- address any other conflicts
- do a `git push -f`
- only see 1 commit but now 160 changes
- rebase the dev branch to my branch `git rebase develop`
- resolve any conflicts (there's like 1 or 2)
- do a `git push -f`
- changes are now correct but the commits show 8 commits again

Comment: Show the exact command-line commands you used, because if you did it the way I would have, you'd still just have one commit, so you must not have typed in the commands I would have :-)

Comment: Can you also explain in more details what actions you chose when running `git rebase -i HEAD~8` ? Squashing commits together shouldn't trigger conflicts, I guess you somehow instructed git to not only do that.

Comment: @torek added details

Comment: @LeGEC added details

Comment: about the conflicts : you don't have to reorder the commits, if you mark a list of commits with "squash", git will ask you to edit the message before creating the commit. Leave the first commit of the sequence with `pick`, you can optionally mark all the intermediate commits with `f` or `fixup`, mark the last one as `s` or `squash`. An alternative in two commands is : `git reset --soft HEAD~8 ; git commit`

Comment: question 1 (just to make sure) : is the target branch of your PR `develop` ? question 2 : is your local `develop` branch in sync with its remote counterpart ?

Comment: @LeGEC the `develop` branch is protected. All branches are created from develop, a PR is opened against develop, then merged upon approval to develop.

Comment: @LeGEC If I have 8 commits doing `get rebase -i HEAD~8` and the first one is very old and the last one is the one relating to the action PR. But I `pick` that first one `squash` the others won't it use that first commit and lose my changes?

Comment: @LeGEC I did the `git rebase -i HEAD~8`, set the first to `pick` and the others to `squash` the exact same thing happens as described in my question.

Comment: OK, I now have an idea as to what is going on. Let me double check: are you working with *three* Git repositories here? One is on your computer, one is your GitHub fork, and the third one is the GitHub repository to which you are making a PR?